# tcl8.5.10 make fail error, Network Simulator2 v2.35 (Cygwin v1.7.32) in Windows 8

Tags: cygwin, tcl, ns2, gcc4

during installation of NS2 v2.35 (Cygwin v1.7.32) in Windows 8 i keep getting this error message:

```
Package gcc4 is not present on your system.

Please install it using Cygwin's setup.exe
before trying to install the ns-2 distribution.
```

I tried downloading the gcc4 package from the setup but it does not show that it has a gcc4 package. So, i downloaded it from internet but the file was empty!!! If i ignore the warning for gcc4 and continue with the installation then i got the following error.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: final l ink failed: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:569: recipe for target `tclsh.exe' failed
make: *** [tclsh.exe] Error 1
tcl8.5.10 make failed! Exiting ...
For problems with Tcl/Tk see http://www.scriptics.com
```

Somebody please help me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest gcc ,i.e., 4.8 not compatible, Go for older versions of gcc like 4.7